# gtk, how to ask the window manager to activate the main window

Tags: gtk, gtk2

I help maintain Xournal. One feature we support is making a screenshot.
We do this by activating the root window and then taking a screenshot.

The issue that I am having is that after the screenshot is made, the active window remains the root window. How do I ask gtk to make the main window of xournal the active one?

I have used gtk_widget_grab_focus but that does not seem to work.

thank you.

--daniel

Comment: I highly doubt you can ask a GUI toolkit to focus a window. That's the window manager's job. It'll most likely depend on your OS and window manager.

Comment: For my understanding, if you make the shot, what is the difference between `root` window and `main` window? The order of things is not completely clear to me.  Anyway, should be very well doable, but not so much from within Gtk, is that a problem?. (Linux, right?)

Comment: Hi @dmg, did you notice my question? ^

Comment: Sorry I didn't reply earlier. The issue is that, the screenshot is taken (that works), control goes back to Xournal, but xournal is no longer the active window. The active window is the one that the screenshot was taken from (root or another application). I want to tell the window manager: please activate me again.

Comment: Does your code know that taking the screenshot has ended? Maybe [gtk_window_present](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/GtkWindow.html#gtk-window-present) could help you?